# vs code & mingw not using io devices

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, io, mingw, execution

I've recently installed vs code ide & mingw compiler on my laptop, but the problem is that whenever I run any code which requires any io operation other than printing on screen, it just doesn't use any io device at all. Besides this, it isn't even printing characters properly on screen

[image: Even this simple code just keeps on running indefinitely & doesn't take any response from my keyboard at all.]
Even this simple code just keeps on running indefinitely & doesn't take any response from my keyboard at all.[image: as you can see here, the place where I should've heard a beep, it just writes 'bel']
as you can see here, the place where I should've heard a beep, it just writes 'bel'
[image: Here, the character that should've been printed didn't got printed, instead a question mark was the one to get printed]
Here, the character that should've been printed didn't got printed, instead a question mark was the one to get printed
[image: Here , a vertical tab should've been printed, instead this vierd 'vt' is being printed]
Here , a vertical tab should've been printed, instead this vierd 'vt' is being printed

Answer (score 0):

All your code examples are invalid

1. `"%d"` is for printing integers not pointers. It is Undefined Behaviour
2. It displays that you try to print special char 'bell'.
3. `"%c"` and character code 219 - it is implementation-defined and on your system, it displays this strange char.
4. Same as above - it displays information that you try to print special char vertical tabulation  (vt in red box)

I do not see any problems here.

Comment: 1) I understood this synrax mistake. 2) It should actually print what I'm trying to do, instead of printing that in english (i.e., for '\a, there should be a beep instead of printing 'bel', similarly for '\v', it should print a vertical tab instead of printing 'vt'). 3) I did used vs code with mingw earlier, it it used to print character perfectly. It is after resetting my laptop that I reinstalled them, and now it is doing this strange thing. 4) same as (3).

Comment: Also, it just doesn't take any input as well. Used scanf many times. See the 1st image and its caption

Comment: @Tauqeer do you see how this tab is called? (output)

Comment: What? I didn't understood your last comment